# Cricket Galaxy S8 Use on AT&T

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

Can I use a Samsung Galaxy S8 from Cricket on AT&T without having it unlocked?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, Cricket (and other MVNO branded devices) cannot be used on another network, even their "parent" network, like AT&T in this case, without being SIM unlocked by the owning carrier. It is not the same as AT&T branded phones which CAN be used on it's MVNO's (like Cricket or H2O) without being unlocked.